# React and Redux this.props.posts is undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I try to follow a tutorial like a Blog with React and Redux but in the `PostList` I have error in the bind of reducer, just I want render the function `renderPost` calling the reducer object with a `map` of `posts`

What is the error in my code ?

this is my component **`PostList`**:

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect } from 'react-redux';
import {cargaPost} from '../acciones/index';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
class ListaPost extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.fetchPost();
    }
    renderPost () {
        return this.props.posts.map( post => {
            <li className="list-group-item" key={post.id}>
                <span className="text-right">{post.categories}</span>
            </li>
        })
    }
    render() { 
        // const { posts } = this.props;
        // if (!posts) {
        //   return <div>Loading...</div>
        // }
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="text-right">
                    <Link
                    to="/posts/new" 
                    >
                    <button 
                    type="button" 
                    className="btn btn-info">
                    Nuevo Post
                    </button>

                    </Link>
                </div>

                <ul className="list-group">
                    {this.renderPost()}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { posts: state.todos }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchPost: cargaPost})(ListaPost);
```

and my **reducerPosts**

```
import {FETCH_POST} from '../acciones/index';

const estadoInicial = { todos:[], unPost: null }
// PostReducer
export default function(state=estadoInicial, accion) {
    switch(accion.type) {
        case FETCH_POST:
            return {...state, todos: accion.payload.data }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

my **index** file

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import PostReducer from './PostReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    posts: PostReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `mapStateToProps` instead of `state.todos` it should be `state.posts.todos`. See below code:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { posts: state.posts.todos }
}
```

Here your rootReducer will return the `state` of the store with have key `posts` inside it (which is for all reducers you are combining into root reducer), and in `posts` you have your `todos`.

Comment: i edit the code but keep the error Hriday check my repo please

Comment: @GerardoBautista which repo?

Comment: shouldn't you return action in api callback here? `const solicitud = axios.get(URL)
    .then( res => { console.log(res) })
    return {
        type: FETCH_POST,
        payload: solicitud
    } ` For that you will need to use [redux-thunk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk)

Answer (score 3):

I think this, in your `mapStateToProps`,

```
return { posts: state.todos }
```

should be

```
return { posts: state.posts }
```

or if you want to get just the todos, then:

```
return { posts: state.posts.todos }
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

and fix the code but I still show the error, please check my repo
https://github.com/emeery/blog

Answer (score 0):

use this code in your mapStateToProps

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { posts: state.posts }
}
```